# A problem with colorbar applied to contourf in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

Given `X_train` data associated with a model `bgmm`, I have a contour plot as follows.

```
x = np.linspace(4, 11)
y = np.linspace(6, 11)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
XX = np.array([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()]).T
Z = -bgmm.score_samples(XX)
Z = Z.reshape(X.shape)

plt.style.use('seaborn-white')
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, levels=np.logspace(0, 1, 5), cmap='RdGy')
plt.clabel(CS, inline=True, fontsize=8)
plt.imshow(Z, extent=[4, 11, 6, 11], origin='lower',
            cmap='RdGy', alpha=0.5)
CB = plt.colorbar()
plt.scatter(X_train[:, 0], X_train[:, 1], 0.8)
plt.show()
```

[image]

As one can see, the range of colorbar is not correct. If I instead consider `CB = plt.colorbar(CS)`, the range gets fixed, but I lose the colors of colorbar:

[image]

So, how to fix the range without losing colors?

Comment: The contour lines seem to agree with the values of the colorbar, are you sure it's wrong? Try printing the minimum and maximum values of Z

Comment: `Z` range is indeed compatible with the first colorbar. I thought the colorbar numbers have to be the same as the numbers on the contours of the plot (say, 10.000, 5.623, etc). Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, they're independent. By default, `imshow` will make a colormap between the minimum and maximum values of the Z array, which is what the colorbar takes, while setting `levels` in `contour` only tells it which lines to draw

Comment: @AJBiffl: Thanks for this explanation!